# Taking user input as string and convert it into executable code C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi i am quite new with C# and i am trying to create an application which takes user input and converts it to code, and run it. I have followed a few guides but i get the same error everytime. I am using Microsoft.Csharp and system.codedom. Is there another way to do this or can somebody help me with this error. This code is part of my unity game and is placed inside one of my scripts.

The type forwarder for type 'Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider' in assembly 'System.CodeDom' causes a cycle i get this error all the time. All the examples i can find are quite old and they all cause the same error. I get the same error with microsoft.codedom.providers.dotnetcompilerplatform.

```
    private static string CreateExecuteMethodTemplate(string content)
    {
    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    builder.Append("using System;");
    builder.Append("\r\nnamespace Lab");
    builder.Append("\r\n{");
    builder.Append("\r\npublic sealed class Cal");
    builder.Append("\r\n{");
    builder.Append("\r\npublic static object Execute()");
    builder.Append("\r\n{");
    builder.AppendFormat("\r\nreturn {0};", content);
    builder.Append("\r\n}");
    builder.Append("\r\n}");
    builder.Append("\r\n}");

    return builder.ToString();
}

private static object Execute(string content)
{
    var codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();

    var compilerParameters = new CompilerParameters
    {
        GenerateExecutable = false,
        GenerateInMemory = true
    };

    compilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.dll");

    string sourceCode = CreateExecuteMethodTemplate(content);
    CompilerResults compilerResults = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParameters, 
    sourceCode);
    Assembly assembly = compilerResults.CompiledAssembly;
    Type type = assembly.GetType("Lab.Cal");
    MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("Execute");

    return methodInfo.Invoke(null, null);
}
```

Comment: C# isn't really meant as a scripting language.  Unity apps typically use Lua for scripting.

Comment: Not sure if that's the issue but what would `return {0};` do exactly?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to allow users to dynamically compile C# code, instead of having them use the Visual Studio IDE?  Are you trying to script your application?  There might be better ways of accomplishing your goals than using CodeDOM to dynamically compile code (which can be dangerous, from a security perspective).

Comment: Its a game meant to teach people basic coding, meaning they can press some buttons and the character in the game follows those commands. The buttons save those commands as strings and show them in a terminal, and then the user can run those commands pressing another button. All the commands are saved as strings.

Comment: What are you using for the value of `content`?

Comment: The code which the user inputs

Comment: Unfortunately, my crystal ball seems to be failing currently. What is the user inputting when you test it?

Comment: I cant test it since i get that error.

Answer (score 1):

Given your idea for gameplay I do believe you'd be better off designing an in-game set of instructions instead of "allowing your users to actually code".

I understand that it is not exactly an answer to your question but I'd like to suggest an alternative approach to the problem whatsoever.

Imagine that inside a game you provide them with a simplified IDE and custom-made simple "scripting language" which then in turn you within the game's engine parse into actions.

Like you could start with tutorial level in a form of:

1. Left half of the screen could be visualization of a current state (people will find it much more intuitive if they'll be able to see what their code is actually doing visually) - such as a yellow square for player's position and a green square somewhere up ahead as a place where player ought to get.
2. Right half of the screen would then be an IDE for player.

Now, you would design some in-game commands such as: "Move(int xDirection, int yDirection)" or "Do(x times)"
And the player could script in the IDE example code such as:

```
   Do(10)
   {
       Move(0, +1);
   }
```

And once player "runs" the code he would see the yellow square moving upwards by "10 units".

For the sake of visibility you could pause for a moment between every "Do" loop so that you can notice what's happening in every loop repetition.

Comment: Yeah my game has a terminal and some buttons which adds some predefined code inside that terminal, i have decided to solve this issue in a completely different way. I will instead manually read the input string, and use those predefined methods inside the string and execute some functions related to those strings. My original idea was to just convert that input string directly into C# code but that is a bit risky and i cant make it work.

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much what I had in mind and suggested. I do believe that this is valid approach to creating a game. The original idea of yours is just spiked with things bound to explode at some point. I'll keep my fingers crossed. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you this approach is harder but much safer, and less vulnerable to hacking.